# Credit card check using Luhn algorithim

Tags: java

I am trying to make an application in JAVA that will check whether a user-entered credit card number is valid.

These are the steps for modulus 10 to check:

Step1:  double every second digit from right to left. If doubling of a digit results in a two-digit number, add up the two digits to get a single-digit number.

Step2: now add all the single digit numbers from step1

Step3: add all digits in the odd places from right to left in the card number

Step4: sum the results from step 2 and step 3

Step 5: if the results from step 4 is divisible by 10, the card number is valid; otherwise, it is invalid. In this case, the card number is not valid – because 75 not divisible by 10.

My issue so far is that every card number I try (using valid numbers) I get told that it is invalid. I tried using the debugging tool and it looks like my value for sum is always wrong. I need help figuring out where I messed up in the calculations or if I am missing something.

```
public class CreditCardChecker {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter credit card number to check validity: ");
    System.out.println();
    String cardNo = sc.next();
    int sum = FindSum(cardNo);

    if ((sum % 10) == 0) {
        System.out.println("The card number is VALID.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The card number is INVALID");
    }

}

public static int FindSum(String cardNo) {

    //CONVERTING CARD NUMBER INTO AN ARRAY
    int[] digits = new int[cardNo.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < cardNo.length(); i++) {
        digits[i] = Character.getNumericValue(cardNo.charAt(i));
    }

    //DOUBLE EVERY OTHER NUMBER FROM RIGHT TO LEFT
    for (int i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {

        digits[i] += digits[i];

        if (digits[i] > 9) {
            digits[i] = digits[i] - 9;
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        sum += digits[i];
    }

    sum *= 9;
    return sum;

}

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `cardNo` when you run your code and type in a number? If you print that to the console what does it show?

Comment: You need to ignore the right-most digit of the original card number. That digit is the checksum digit and should not be included when calculating the Luhn checksum.

Comment: @csmckelvey I tried to print it to the console and nothing shows up

Comment: @Bobulous In the example given they used all 16 digits of the card in the sum, so wouldn't that mean I don't ignore it?

Comment: I think you are taking a newline as input, not the number.

Comment: @csmckelvey how should I change it to take the number? is it an issue with this line? `String cardNo = sc.next();`

Comment: That, combined with the extra line you printed right before. Try calling nextLine 2 times instead to get input. First will consume the newline, and second will get you your number (as a string).

Comment: @WilliamLoveless Change your for loop where you loop through and double every other number from left to right to be `for(int i = digits.length -2;i>=0;i-=2)`

Comment: @csmckelvey what would it look like calling it twice? If I set the value of cardNo to sc.nextLine() two times would it not just be doing the same thing each time?

Comment: @Matthew thank you for pointing that out. I did change that but I am still not getting it to function properly.

Comment: It would not do the same thing both times. As I explained, when you call the method the first time it will consume the new line character and your input variable will hold that. When you call the method a second time you will now be consuming the actual number you typed in so your input variable will hold the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your implementation of that step:

> Step1: double every second digit from right to left. If doubling of a digit results in a two-digit number, add up the two digits to get a single-digit number.

You start iterating with the *last*(nth) digit of the credit card number, while you should start with (n-1)th digit. That is, change:

```
for (int i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2)
```

to

```
for (int i = digits.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
```

Also, have in mind that your `FindSum(String cardNo)` method will only work for `String`s without any spaces in them (which is how you may get your input).

Comment: I corrected this part and it is still telling me that valid card numbers are invalid.

Comment: @WilliamLoveless I've just checked it with some examples from the internet and my own credit card and it works well. Can you give me an example of some number that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Nevermind I messed up something small as I was making these changes. You are correct.